# Error:string index out of range, defining a function

Tags: python, python-3.5

I'm practicing coding on codingbat.com since I'm a complete beginner in python, and here is one of the exercises:

Given a string, return a new string made of every other char starting with the first, so "Hello" yields "Hlo".

Here is my attempt at defining the function string_bits(str):

```
def string_bits(str):
  char = 0
  first = str[char]
  for char in range(len(str)):
    char += 2
    every_other = str[char]
return (first + every_other)
```

Running the code gives an error. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: ...your string index is out of range. This shouldn't be surprising, given that you're iterating up to the last index *and adding two to it*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think IndexError is raised when 'char' equals to the _penultimate_ index (since we're adding 2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A different approach, with an explanation:

If you need to handle a sentence, where spaces would be included, you can do this using slicing. On a string slicing works as:

```
[start_of_string:end_of_string:jump_this_many_char_in_string]
```

So, you want to jump only every second letter, so you do:

```
[::2]
```

The first two are empty, because you just want to step every second character.

So, you can do this in one line, like this:

```
>>> " ".join(i[::2] for i in "Hello World".split())
'Hlo Wrd'
```

What just happened above, is we take our string, use `split` to make it a list. The split by default will split on a space, so we will have:

```
["Hello", "World"]
```

Then, what we will do from there, is using a comprehension, iterate through each item of the list, which will give us a word at a time, and from there we will perform the desired string manipulation per `i[::2]`.

The comprehension is: ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions))

```
i[::2] for i in "Hello World".split()
```

Finally, we call `"".join` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)), which will now change our list back to a string, to finally give us the output:

```
"Hlo Wrd"
```

Check out the slicing section from the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html

Comment: Very helpful and a clear explanation. Slicing makes the code a lot more simple

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the char += 2 returns a value greater than len(str) as len(str)-1 (the range) + 2 is longer than the string. You could do:

```
def string_bits(string):

    if len(string) == 2:
        return string[0]

    result = ''
    for char in range(0,len(string),2):#range created value sin increments of two
        result += string[char]
    return result
```

A more succinct method would be:

```
def string_bits(string):
    return string[::2]
```

You should avoid using 'str' as a variable name as it is a reserved word by Python.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, for me:

1. You should not use str as a variable name as it is a python built-in function (replace str by my_str for example)
2. For example, 'Hello' length is 5, so 0 <= index <= 4. Here you are trying to access index 3+2=5 (when char = 3) in your for loop.

You can achieve what you want with the following code:

```
def string_bits(my_str):
  result = ""
  for char in range(0, len(my_str), 2):
    result += my_str[char]
  return result
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting means that you are trying to get the nth letter of a string that has less than n characters.

Answer (score 0):

As another suggestion, strings are Sequence-types in Python, which means they have a lot of built-in functionalities for doing exactly what you're trying to do here. See [Built-in Types - Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) for more information, but know that sequence types support slicing - that is, selection of elements from the sequence.

So, you could slice your string like this:

```
def string_bits(input_string):
    return input_string[::2]
```

Meaning "take my input_string from the start (:) to the end (:) and select every second (2) element"